# Unity内のfor文に関しての質問です。

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity初心者です。

Unity内のfor文に関しての質問です。
今、サイコロででた目の数だけキャラクターをマスの上で
動かすプログラムを組んでみたのですが、
上下左右に1マス、1マスずつ指定した方向に動かしたいのに、
一度方向を指定した瞬間に一気にその方向に動いてしまいます。
どのように修正すれば、入力待ちしながら1マス1マス動かすことができるようになりますか。
以下プログラミング内容になります。
updateの中で実行しています。

よろしくお願いします。

※d62.lastresultはサイコロの出た目です。

```cs
public void MoveMain(){

    Dice2 d62 = dice2.GetComponent ();
    if (d62.lastresult != 0 && jj == false) {
        for (int i = 0; i < d62.lastresult; i++) {
            if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.W) ) {
                this.transform.position += new Vector3 (0, 0, 1);
                jj=true;
            }else if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.S)){
                this.transform.position += new Vector3 (0, 0, -1);
                jj=true;
            }else if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.A)){
                this.transform.position += new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0);
                jj=true;
            }else if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.D)){
                this.transform.position += new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);
                jj=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void MoveMain(){

    Dice2 d62 = dice2.GetComponent ();
    if (d62.lastresult != 0 && jj == false) {
        for (int i = 0; i < d62.lastresult; i++) {
            if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.W) ) {
                this.transform.position += new Vector3 (0, 0, 1);
                jj=true;
            }else if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.S)){
                this.transform.position += new Vector3 (0, 0, -1);
                jj=true;
            }else if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.A)){
                this.transform.position += new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0);
                jj=true;
            }else if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.D)){
                this.transform.position += new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);
                jj=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

上記だと、そもそも同一フレーム内にすべて処理してしまいます。
そのため、フレーム別で管理してあげる必要があります。

> 1フレーム目：入力
>   2フレーム目：(入力を検知している場合)移動
>   3フレーム目：(入力を検知している場合)移動
>   ・
>   ・
>   ・

ですので事象ごとにフラグで管理してコントロールしてやれば、
質問者さんがしたいことは実現できるかと思います。

**追記**

上記のコードですが、

> if (d62.lastresult != 0 && jj == false) {

ここでは、ダイスの結果が0以外、jj?が偽である場合の分岐です。

> if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.W) ) {
>   else if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.S)){
>   else if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.A)){
>   else if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.D)){

これいずれかが真だと、同一フレーム内では常に真の結果が返ります。

> jj=true;

これが本来ストッパーの役割を果たすものだと思いますが、果たせていません。

一度箇条書きでいいので、実現したいことを時系列を並べて設計をしてみてください。
必要であればさらに追記します。

Answer (score 0):

コルーチンで入力待ちすれば、
以下の様な書き方できるんじゃないかな？

```
public void MoveMain(){
    StartCoroutine(CoMoveMain());
}

IEnumerator CoMoveMain(){
    Dice2 d62 = dice2.GetComponent();
    for(int i=0;i<d62.lastresult;i++){
        While(!Input.anyKeyDown){ yield return 0; }

        if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.W) ) {
            this.transform.position += new Vector3 (0, 0, 1);
        }else if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.S)){
            this.transform.position += new Vector3 (0, 0, -1);
        }else if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.A)){
            this.transform.position += new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0);
        }else if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.D)){
            this.transform.position += new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);
        }
        else{
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

※Transamさんからご指摘がありましたので加筆してみました。
...こういうことなのかな(^^;？

Comment: コルーチンで実装するのであれば、その点を考慮した部分を説明する必要があると思います。そのままの実装だと問題が出ます。

Comment: 言葉足らずでお手数をおかけいたします。

まず投稿者さんが初心者であるという点、Updateで処理をしている、
という2点を踏まえて説明する必要があると思います。

Inoueさんが今回説明したのだと、Updateに記載してしまうと
毎度コルーチンが発生してしまうので、問題になるといった感じです。
この点親切に説明してあげる必要がある、という話です！
回答に対して質問者さんがどう受け取るのか、という配慮が最低限必要という話ですね。

Comment: なるほど、そういう事ですね（＾＾；
丁寧な返信ありがとうございます！

コルーチン中はフラグを立てて回避すれば・・・とも思いましたが、
投稿者さんが初心者ということを加味すると、コルーチンの説明からになっちゃいますね。であれば、Update中で状態をみながら回す方が今は理解しやすいのかもしれませんね。

自分も回答なれしていないので、思わぬ所で良い勉強になりました！
ありがとうございますm（*_ _）m